# In which form Data store in wp_post table of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In which form Data store in wp_post table of wordpress . I am sure it's not in json format.

Comment: Okay, so this is a very low quality question, your question is kinda programming, but there is no issue to fix, have you searched google for this? This is not what we are here for

Comment: It store data in serialized array in wp_post table